# I wish to enroll for the course, but I need to know, first, what would be the computer configuration required to run and work on Blender, effectively?

Tags: system

I wish to enroll for the course, but, before that, I need to know what would be the ideal computer configuration required to run and work on Blender, effectively?

Comment: Here you have the requrements: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: On windows I've never, ever had it not run. It's also extremely light weight.